# How to log modified works using promise()

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, console.log

```
const works = [
  { name: "CCS", workStatus: { isComplete: true } },
  { name: "CCB", workStatus: { isComplete: false } },
  { name: "CCF", workStatus: { isComplete: false } },
];
works.forEach(function (item) {
  setTimeout(function(){
    if (item.name === "CCF") {
      item.workStatus.isComplete = true;
    }
  }, 3000);
});
console.log("works",works);
```

If each forEach loop is taking at least 3sec to execute.....

How to log the final works which has been modified by forEach loop? (**using promise**)

the current console will log the old works only, How to log modified works here?

Comment: No, the forEach loop does not take 3 seconds to execute, because it's executed synchronously and only creates 3 timeouts, each of which will be called after 3 seconds. If you want to log the modifed data, you have to log it in the callback of the timeout.

Comment: @derpirscher  Can you please give a clear-cut view on this?

Answer (score 2):

You could for instance create a method that modifies your item and resolves, once it's finished. And then use `Promise.all()` to wait for all modifications to be finished. Once `Promise.all` resolves, printout your modified array ...

```js
const works = [
  { name: "CCS", workStatus: { isComplete: true } },
  { name: "CCB", workStatus: { isComplete: false } },
  { name: "CCF", workStatus: { isComplete: false } },
];

function m(item) {
  return new Promise(res => {
     setTimeout(() => {
       if (item.name === "CCF")
         item.workStatus.isComplete = true;
       res();
     }, 3000);
  });
}

Promise.all(works.map(x => m(x)))
  .then(_ => console.log(works));
```

But as it doesn't seem very reasonable to use the same method for all items, because there may be different modifications for each item, you could check beforehand, and just call the modifier for items that need to be modified

```js
const works = [
  { name: "CCS", workStatus: { isComplete: true } },
  { name: "CCB", workStatus: { isComplete: false } },
  { name: "CCF", workStatus: { isComplete: false } },
];

function m(item) {
  return new Promise(res => {
     setTimeout(() => {
       item.workStatus.isComplete = true;
       res();
     }, 3000);
  });
}

let p = [];
works.forEach(x => {
  if (x.name === "CCF") p.push(m(x));
});

Promise.all(p)
  .then(_ => console.log(works));
```